# NSNotificationCenter can't set the activity indicator to hidden

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiactivityindicatorview

hello i created a nsnotificationcenter in appdelegate.when the download is finished it sends a notification. i have a activity indicator on my class and i what to hide it when the download is finished but it doesn't work. i can see my nslog but it doesn't hide the acitivyindicator.

here is my code:

viewdidload:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(refreshView:) name:@"loadingFinished" object:nil];
```

my function:

```
-(void)refreshView:(NSNotification*)notification
{

    activity.hidden = YES;
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled =YES;
    NSLog(@"alles geladen zeiger wird geladen");



}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are at any other thread, then it will not work cz UI not work in inner thread. use this

```
-(void)refreshView:(NSNotification*)notification
{


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
 activity.hidden = YES;
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled =YES;

        });    
    NSLog(@"alles geladen zeiger wird geladen");



}
```

Answer (score 0):

A notification callback may not be called on the main thread, but all your UI updates must be done in the main thread. So on your notification callback, use `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(refreshViewFromMainThread)]`, and declare a new method:

```
- (void)refreshViewFromMainThread
{
    activity.hidden = YES;
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```